# How do I log outbound HTTP requests in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, meteor

Is there a Meteor package that would enable me to do that?

Alternatively, is there a way to use a node package like [global-request-logger](https://github.com/meetearnest/global-request-logger) to log outbound http traffic for a Meteor app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can use npm modules in your Meteor application.

Here is one way to include them:

1. Run `meteor add meteorhacks:npm`.
2. Create a `packages.json` file in your project root directory.
3. Insert `{ "global-request-logger": "0.0.1" }` in your `packages.json` file to list the dependency to the desired npm module `global-request-logger`.
4. Import the module and initialise it:

---

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    var globalLog = Meteor.npmRequire('global-request-logger');
    globalLog.initialize();
}
```

---

Please note that most of the npm modules provide asynchronous API's with callbacks. Unfortunately, you can't directly use them in your Meteor application. However, you can use **async utilities** to *bridge the gap* between synchronous Meteor APIs and asynchronous npm modules.

Read more about `meteorhacks:async`'s [async utilities](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-async).

---

There is also a Meteor package available, which logs HTTP requests. The package is called `meteor-log-requests` and is provided by [Evented Mind](https://github.com/eventedmind). At the moment the package is unpublished, as a consequence you need to install it as a local package if you want to use it.

Here is how:

1. Clone the `meteor-log-requests` [GitHub repository](https://github.com/eventedmind/meteor-log-requests).
2. Create a `packages` directory in your project root if it does not exist.
3. Copy the `meteor-log-requests` package in your `packages` directory.
4. Add the package via `meteor add log-requests`.

The log output looks like this:

```
I20150730-07:40:28.627(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /
I20150730-07:40:28.795(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /20ae2c8d51b2507244e598844414ecdec2615ce3.css
I20150730-07:40:28.800(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18
I20150730-07:40:28.812(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/meteor.js?43b7958c1598803e94014f27f5f622b0bddc0aaf
I20150730-07:40:28.848(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/json.js?e22856eae714c681199eabc5c0710b904b125554
I20150730-07:40:28.852(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/base64.js?1a63019243b73298e2964e6d4680f25bca657726
I20150730-07:40:28.857(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/ejson.js?71047b64b5196348bdbe5fd5eea9ac97a5a9eb14
I20150730-07:40:28.946(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/logging.js?07e201b648f16be8435a4f666156995eeda0c750
I20150730-07:40:28.966(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/reload.js?da8974b7231dd8c0caccb5f322dcf97329d486d1
I20150730-07:40:28.970(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/tracker.js?6d0890939291d9780f7e2607ee3af3e7f98a3d9c
I20150730-07:40:28.986(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/random.js?fe7b46080c91ce482acf6fc326afbc5b176f0502
I20150730-07:40:28.991(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/retry.js?1f1dd2c35d300110fdaba51ce4473583bc3bf031
I20150730-07:40:28.997(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/check.js?ac81167b8513b85b926c167bba423981b0c4cf9c
I20150730-07:40:29.049(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/id-map.js?9ea6eaae8d74693ce2505a858d9a5e60cf191298
I20150730-07:40:29.071(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/ordered-dict.js?bf8af2f26c8d96bf8b2e6b407d3ed69f23c2cd37
I20150730-07:40:29.087(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/geojson-utils.js?81b79d5cf96d00b4b7a28987debcffb665c17526
I20150730-07:40:29.102(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/minimongo.js?af9eb9d7447544ca9b839a3dcf7ed2da2209b56c
I20150730-07:40:29.109(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706
I20150730-07:40:29.115(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/insecure.js?3dc9d4a2dad55999b5b15a447d57f3d5fb66b290
I20150730-07:40:29.170(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/mongo.js?3cfe0c5981c197df33036a37574850f057e934a6
I20150730-07:40:29.182(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/autoupdate.js?9a5ea03bf057815385bf569c7acc2c285c005491
I20150730-07:40:29.195(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/meteor-platform.js?499a2f8522e25820b1153c69a92751ccaae507b3
I20150730-07:40:29.200(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/autopublish.js?c3059a78bb200b171099fc4fa1a9345101790ddb
I20150730-07:40:29.264(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/log-requests.js?b9d6c721fd5a35edc5998a3296966595fe398910
I20150730-07:40:29.286(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/jquery.js?dd8bac56f8fd3666d433d2285ae01e52597cc51a
I20150730-07:40:29.301(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/meteorhacks_npm.js?604e35d5437f43224cde2c1f9e5e9aace95a9a95
I20150730-07:40:29.304(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/npm-container.js?c4195e22b5a0a7239a415a3d95b3b702c34fa28d
I20150730-07:40:29.315(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/webapp.js?e1be090051b82f046484dccc2de7d747e50c7328
I20150730-07:40:29.334(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/deps.js?504589e1e9585dec8f9f6094e5a87b22de3783a1
I20150730-07:40:29.453(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/reactive-dict.js?1cb61826ceb23464171f17c2191c7e04a9b91508
I20150730-07:40:29.466(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/session.js?daf192a7244079d45db32a6fc26ebc3881fc1aa3
I20150730-07:40:29.469(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/livedata.js?718526445deb4d9baacb6d92c551adea1d36c1e1
I20150730-07:40:29.473(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/htmljs.js?567eb96d5d22631c03d6aca6afa4c42f0d1295f2
I20150730-07:40:29.476(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/observe-sequence.js?0532a9dd76dd78f543eb4d79a1e429df186d8bde
I20150730-07:40:29.482(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/reactive-var.js?20335b7b37165980ddd9f23943b2e5b00aae1cc2
I20150730-07:40:29.553(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51
I20150730-07:40:29.577(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/ui.js?5a663333fd30f8fd913f110e0ef779e84f67c4b8
I20150730-07:40:29.586(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/templating.js?376767bb0d2463b3b2615a1b90e77f6b22d39d7b
I20150730-07:40:29.588(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/spacebars.js?7bafbe05ec09b6bbb6a3b276537e4995ab298a2f
I20150730-07:40:29.594(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/launch-screen.js?495e58cf2465ba553324c68301cc62076b1fda1e
I20150730-07:40:29.601(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/meteorhacks_async.js?e687b9e863dc811fb3f313d1c6f237c7a2b1924b
I20150730-07:40:29.662(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /packages/global-imports.js?28b039ee71a940b59e6694e1b2c8c7555daafc2d
I20150730-07:40:29.669(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /template.meteor-log.js?a9c3a806e3371cc14c0e8d6f86b73b7bf2ef19d7
I20150730-07:40:29.675(2) (log_requests.js:11) 127.0.0.1: GET /meteor-log.js?a4f638a50228714016abbc604c243f65b057e771
```

---

You may want to log [DDP](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/ddp/DDP.md) messages as well, since DDP is the protocol which is used for communication between clients and the server (concerning publications, MongoDB operations & Meteor methods). To log DDP messages, you can use the [Meteor DDP Analyzer](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-ddp-analyzer):

1. Run `sudo npm install -g ddp-analyzer`.
2. Start the DDP Analyzer Proxy with `ddp-analyzer-proxy` via the terminal.
3. Set the DDP default connection via `export DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL=http://localhost:3030`.
4. Finally, start your app with `meteor`.

Logs will be dumped by `ddp-analyzer-proxy` in your terminal:

[image: Meteor_DDP_Analyzer]

Read more about [DDP](https://meteorhacks.com/introduction-to-ddp).

Comment: Great comprehensive answer, thank you.  I did end up getting global-request-logger to work.  The other package you suggested, meteor-log-requests, is for logging inbound traffic - whereas I was looking to log outbound.